# limiting x-axis by the facets used in qplot, R

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, facet

I was trying to create a plot for each of the 4 quarters in my data. So I used:

```
qplot(date, mape, data = df, facets = .~quarter)
```

The resulting plot was: 
[image]

The X-axis is using all the months present in the "date" column - from Jan - Dec. But the data on the chart is limited to the months of the quarter for e.g. Jan-Feb-March in the Q1 facet, Apr-May-June for Q2 etc. How can I limit the x-axis to the months corresponding to the quarter only?

as an alternate, I did this but its not exactly how I want to display my data: `qplot(strftime(df$date, format = "%b"), mape, data = predicted.modelset)`

Comment: as an alternate, I did this but its not exactly how I want to display my data: `qplot(strftime(df$date, format = "%b"), mape, data = predicted.modelset)`

Comment: Hard to know without your data, but try this: `qplot(date, mape, data = df) + facet_grid(.~quarter,scales="free_x")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best if you could provide data for this but I am pretty sure the following will work:

```
qplot(date, mape, data = df) + facet_wrap(~quarter,scales="free_x") #without a dot before ~
```

Comment: Why do you say OP can't use `facet_grid(...)`: `ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg))+geom_point()+facet_grid(.~cyl,scales="free_x")` sets the x-axis according to the x-range in each facet.

Comment: I had tried to use it in a similar problem and it didn't work for me as far as I remember. I will look again. Hard to recheck without data... It seems to be working here for sure. I will remove it from my answer. Thanks for this.

Comment: I found the example. I can't reproduce it in the comment I 'm afraid. I wasn't able to make it work with geom_bar() not geom_point() if this helps.